# Generate Batch QR codes from PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using PHP QR Code library and it works fine to generate one QR Code. What I require is alter my php to display a bulk of QR codes which are generated from the text field (shown below) and which will be comma separated. This is the script I have:

echo "

## PHP QR Code

---

";

```
//set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
$PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

//html PNG location prefix
$PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

include "qrlib.php";    

//ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
    mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';


//processing form input
//remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
$errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], array('L','M','Q','H')))
    $errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];    

$matrixPointSize = 4;
if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
    $matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);


if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) { 

    //it's very important!
    if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
        die('data cannot be empty! <a href="?">back</a>');

    // user data
    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
    QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2); 


} else {    

    //default data
    echo 'You can provide data in GET parameter: <a href="?data=like_that">like that</a><hr/>';    
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);


}    

//display generated file
echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
```

echo $filename;

```
//config form
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Data:&nbsp;<input name="data" value="'.(isset($_REQUEST['data'])?htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data']):'PHP QR Code :)').'" />&nbsp;
    ECC:&nbsp;<select name="level">
        <option value="L"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='L')?' selected':'').'>L - smallest</option>
        <option value="M"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='M')?' selected':'').'>M</option>
        <option value="Q"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='Q')?' selected':'').'>Q</option>
        <option value="H"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='H')?' selected':'').'>H - best</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
    Size:&nbsp;<select name="size">';

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.(($matrixPointSize==$i)?' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';

echo '</select>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="GENERATE"></form><hr/>';
```

What I need is in the input field called 'value' I will be able to type a series of information separated by comma then be presented with a list of QR barcodes generated from the comma separated list I specify.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact problem ? What have you tried ? What blocks you from doing this by yourself ?

Comment: This is where I'm stuck: $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png'; I cannot figure out how I can use a foreach loop to create a list of png files which will be comma separated via my input box ...

Comment: @Sliq This is what I have tried: I have a php file generating QR Codes in a simple way as follows:  <?php

include "qrlib.php";

QRcode::png('code1');
QRcode::png('code2');

?> Then I created a simple HTML file with the following in order to call the PNGs generated as images:<html>

<img src="index2.php">


</html>  This works but only if in the php file I specify one QRCode. As soon as I include more than one it still shows one. I know this might be easy but I need some help at least to get on the right track. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Declare an empty array before your loop: $array = array(); Add to it during the for each loop{ $array[] = $addedpng; } if you are cycling through a query result set to get the png names.
If you can't process it as an array, and need the csv string, I just do something like: 
`$x = 'DONTNEEDTHISTEXT'; 
foreach($png as $addedpng){$x .= ', '.$addedpng; }

$onlypngs = str_replace("DONTNEEDTHISTEXT, ", "", $x);`